# Interface bloat needs trimming

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Sorry about the bad title, I couldn't think of a more descriptive one.

The Shape ADT I have is steadily getting bigger and more bloated, specifically due to this section of the interface:

```c
 
class Shape() {
    //...
    virtual bool Intersects(const Point& point) const =0;
    virtual bool Intersects(const Line& line) const =0;
    virtual bool Intersects(const Line& line, bool isInfinite) const =0;
    virtual bool Intersects(const Rectangle& rectangle) const =0;
    virtual bool Intersects(const Circle& circle) const =0;
    virtual bool Intersects(const Ellipse& ellipse) const =0;
    virtual bool Intersects(const Triangle& triangle) const =0;
    virtual bool Intersects(const Arc& arc) const =0;
    //...
};
```

every new class that subclasses Shape has to be added into the interface. This is getting old fast. I remember reading somewhere that there was a design pattern to fix the issue. Templates are out of the question: each shape has its own unique way of detecting an intersection with different objects, as such, its no better than what is currently being done.

Comment: Just wondering, what's wrong with templates?

Comment: To further agree with OneOfOne, You can [provide specialized implementations of templates...](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).  Of course, if you don't know the static types at runtime, they won't help.

Comment: @user757808: So is C++.  But it is fast.

Comment: You're probably looking for the Visitor pattern, since you're trying to implement double dispatch.  But your interface would remain bloated...

Comment: Aside maybe for the circle and ellipse, you can basically see a shape as a set of points. Calculating the intersection with that should be pretty easy.

Comment: Just for naming, I wouldn't call an infinite line still a "line" but a "ray". :)

Comment: @user757808: The point of templates isn't performance. Templates allows one to write C++ code that can be generalized to many different situations in a way that's also type-safe. In C the best you can do in that situation is to use things like `void*` and macros, and assembly does not enforce type-safety at all. The fact that it happens to allow us to write type-safe code that's also fast is a bonus.

Comment: @Casey: Since the exact behavior of the `Intersect` function depends on two different objects (e.g. a `Point` and a `Line`), [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) may help you out. C++ doesn't support double dispatch natively, but can be emulated with the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: @In silico: Static type checking and code inlining are two of the benefits of templates, and they certainly effect performance.  But as we've both said, it might not work in this scenario, due to (double) dispatch being required.

Comment: @Xeo: The "isInfinite" parameter is used to distinguish between a segment and a line.

Comment: Honestly, templates are the **perfect** solution to this problem (CRTP). Avoiding them for.. what reason? is just silly.

Comment: @Casey: Are you sure that `Intersects` even should be a part of the interface? Maybe intersection should be done by a separate class `Intersection` that would know about the different implementations. The shapes won't have to know about each other in this design.

Comment: @larsm: Granted that moving the Intersects methods out into another interface, say, IIntersectable, would de-clutter and de-couple the Shape objects, but wouldn't that then move the problem around instead of solving it?

Comment: In silico is right here because he explains what pattern to use, this is the answer to the question Mark Ransom does explain what the suer needs to do, but it's not a solution to the problem itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to realize that as structured, this can't help but break encapsulation. Each intersection function must know the internal workings of two different objects.

The second thing to realize is that this is an n^2 problem, or more precisely n*(n+1)/2. Each time you add a new shape, you must add an intersection function for each of the previous n shapes. Clearly this doesn't scale, which is why you asked for help.

In the real world, the way to handle this problem is to come up with a smaller number of classes that can act as a superset of some of the shapes. For example, your Point, Line, Rectangle, and Triangle could all be expressed as a collection of line segments; your Circle could be an Arc that covers 360 degrees. If exactness is not required, you could approximate every single shape as a collection of Bezier curves and have a single Intersect method that has knowledge of the collection.

Comment: "...In the real world, the way to handle this problem is to come up with a smaller number of classes that can act as a superset of some of the shapes..." I've done this in several of the classes before posting the question. Most of the classes are composites of Points and/or Lines (or std::pairs or std::tuples of them), e.g. Line: 2 Points; Rectangle: 1 Point and a width and height; Circle: 1 Point and a radius; Triangle: 3 Points; Ellipse: 1 Point, and a width and height; Arc: 1 Point, a radius and a degree.

Comment: *continued from previous* Even with this setup defining an intersection between say, two rectangles is completely different from two circles, or two lines, (or a line and anything...); which makes a single intersection method cumbersome. I appreciate the explanation though.

Comment: @Casey Points don't intersect, line segments do. You're using the wrong internal representation for your upper level classes.

Comment: @Casey If the boundaries of two shapes don't intersect, there's only one more thing you need to determine: if one is inside the other.

Comment: The reason everything has a point as a base representation is they include wrappers for a graphics API that has 90% of its implementations as: Foo(int x, int y), Bar(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2), Baz(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3). Much easier to use points directly than try to calculate them all the time.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having is one of using the wrong feature for the task.

You have two objects, each of some indeterminate type, but you do know that it is over a finite set of types. You now want to call a function that will perform some operation on the two of them. And the implementation of this function will change based on *pair* of types; it isn't based on just one type or the other.

OOP isn't going to help you here. You need a different design for this. What you need is a list of functions that perform intersections between the various legal pairs of types. Then, you use a dispatch function to index into this table based on the two types at runtime. So you need a bit of RTTI code to get a type index or something that you can use to dispatch based on.

Comment: Your RTTI recommendation will work, but OOP can be used, too.  As In Silico and I said in the OP comments, to do dynamic dispatch on a *pair* of types ([double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), a special case of [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) - invoke a virtual function based on two types, rather than 1), you can use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), in a cyclic manner.

Comment: @Merlyn: But there's no point in the function being _virtual_ at that point, as no single object can provide an override for newly created object types. Inheritance and polymorphism can't help you.

Comment: It works.  It just has drawbacks (namely, you have to modify the base class if you want to add new unique type pairings).  I will freely admit this drawback, but I don't concede that it doesn't work.  I've tried it, and it does work :)  I've used it for exactly this scenario, too.

Answer (score 2):

Point, Line, Rectangle, Circle, Ellipse, Triangle and Arc is all "Geometry" - you're missing a base class. Or is the common base class "Shape"? If so, you have even more problems (interface Shape knows about it's implementations).

I'd create a common base class and declare one virtual intersect method. You could probably use the visitor pattern to implement actual intersection logic without the base class knowing about all the different implementations.

Comment: Removing the requirement for the base class to know all the derived classes doesn't help much; the real problem is that each derived class must know about every other derived class.